# Wordpress MU with subdomain

Tags: multisite, subdomains, dns

I have done a Network installation on marklab.eu. I've choose subdomain mode because i wolud like to create a subdomain like blog.marklab.eu

I've already install the Domain Mappin plugin.

This is the setting:
Server CNAME domain: marklab.eu (International Domain Names should be in punycode format.)

And then add the Domanin
blog.marklab.eu set as Primary

On my server I create two A record with the IP of marklab.eu and the following NAME

1. *.marklab.eu
2. blog.marklab.eu

That's all  but it doesn't work.
Look at blog.marklab.eu page

What I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your blog subsite is working fine here. When you create a subsite it can take some time for the DNS to update. You may lower your TTL for faster updates.

The blog shows a white page, but I think that's because of there is no theme activated. Since your wp-admin link working.